# Parsing json into custom structures in Python (something like Java JAXB)

Tags: python, json, binding

I know I can parse json in Python using the json or simplejson library. 
However, my understanding is that currently these libraries will populate generic data structures (list and dictionaries).

Is there something in Python for JSON like JAXB in Java for XML ?

For example,

One of my JSON looks like the following.

```
json_content  =  {'return': {'status':'active', 'memory' : { 'total': 21547878238, 'remaining':234787342, 'transferred': 7877482472}}, 'id': 'some-id'}
```

Comment: Your example is a little incomplete, you probably forgot to include what you expect the result of the parse to look like. In any case, take a look at the [`json` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), you can specify custom object hooks on decoding.